# Parsing nested json parsing

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-parser

I'm working to get pictures from facebook using json. exp, [this](http://graph.facebook.com/fundamentalalvarado/?fields=albums.fields%28photos.fields%28source%29%29) returs json object. I tried to get value in it. But it is showing like this

```
 {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#210) Subject must be a page.","code":210}}
```

I'm getting json object if I copy and paste the url. Please tell me why I'm getting this error while trying in java.

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                    Log.d("Json", json.toString());
```

Parse.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
//          is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: is this logcat excepiton

Comment: No. It is the result that I'm getting get from graph.facebook while doing in java

Comment: @srikanth: Do you want me to paste the code

Comment: Can you post your passing  code

Comment: @srikanth: Could you please explain me what is the problem in it.